# Why is income tax generally not in a continuous "spectrum"?

Tags: income-tax

With respect to the countries about which I am familiar, income tax is partitioned into tax "brackets", meaning that the rate of taxation varies discretely. Different tax rates are therefore applied to different "blocks" of an individual's annual income. The UK, for example, also has a personal allowance - a pot of money an individual can earn tax-free.

This system seems counter-intuitive to me - it complicates annual tax calculation, as income needs to first be partitioned. Why not apply a continuous *and* smooth (but obviously non-linear) scale to taxation. The rate would approach a limit and start slow, forming a kind of sigmoid-shaped distribution. The tax rate could then be applied in one motion and could be arguably more "fair."

I'm **editing** this because it seems to have received many responses - which I didn't anticipate, so I'll offer some of my reasoning behind the question.

In my eyes, and from going through some of the comments & answers which skewed my opinion slightly, I see the following pros and cons:

**Pros**

- The commonly held perspective of *"There's no point in taking that job for $N/annum because I'd be taxed through the roof."* at some salary thresholds would be partially diminished.
- There's no two ways about it - it *would* give finer-grained control over income taxation at the expense of  ease-of-understanding. It *could* offer a fairer tax system, in spite of public impression of complexity.
- Tax is digital in many countries - we shouldn't have to be narrow-minded about the possibilities for tax any more. Tax tables are (or at least should be) a thing of the past.

**Cons**

- Personal finance has hitherto been blessed with ease of calculation, even with pen and paper. This would throw a spanner in the works.
- Would there be a limit to how complex the function could become? Could governments exploit the system by making the function so convoluted or employ devious mathematical techniques (e.g. around the rounding of pennies) as to extort certain parts of the populous?
- The system cannot be changed to accommodate one group without affecting all, however marginally. (Actually, this isn't completely true if a piecewise function is adopted, but that's going even further down the rabbit hole.) This would seriously impact political campaigns for example, as intention can not be so easily conveyed.
- The fragile tax legal framework would be seriously threatened by such a major change.

Comment: But the resulting overall tax rate is still a continuous function! Only the marginal tax rate is non-continuous, i.e. the tax rate function is not differentiable. Also, calculating tax in a bracket system is very simple using a pocket calculator and a table: find the highest tax bracket you're in, calculate the tax from that bracket, then add the maximum tax from all lower brackets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do tax brackets work? Do they yield significantly different results than a continuous curve?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/101575/how-do-tax-brackets-work-do-they-yield-significantly-different-results-than-a-c)

Comment: Take a look at a progressive bracket system like the USA's and create a smooth function that generally follows that line.   (as close as reasonably possible to it, since I gather you are not aiming to change the intent of tax law). a) can it be made simple and doable with pencil and paper by most people?

Comment: @amon:  the basic income tax is continuous, but the add-ons can make it discontinuous.  In the US, if you are on Medicare the premiums jump based on your Modified Adjusted Gross Income.  For a single return, if you are at 87000/yr or below the 2019 part B premium was 144.60/mo.  At 87001/yr it was 202.40/mo, an increase of over 700/year.  The first year I got out of school (decades ago) the last 200 my wife and I earned was taxed at over 100% through a quirk in the CA income tax law plus the basic federal income tax and social security.

Comment: I wonder now more fundamentally why income is taxed at all. Now that for the last 13 years or so we live in an economy completely dependent on stimulus from the govt and central banks, and now that households need direct stimulus too, and that the govt borrows but the fed/central bank writes off the debt, what value is tax?

Comment: @Frank: See Germany in the Interbellum for what happens if you finance government spending with central bank money printing.  There's a reason it's called the Interbellum ("between wars").

Comment: Cross-site **duplicate**: [*Why isn’t the tax system continuous rather than bracketed?*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/42362/130)

Comment: @MSalters A more apt comparison I think would be with Japan, which entered the same state the rest of the world fell into as far back as the 90s, and continues to fund >200% debt-gdp ratios, and continues to write off govt debt. As an aside, I think maintaining tax policy as though nothing has changed is merely turning a blind eye to a huge elephant in the room, that the economy as most know it has fundamentally altered in a way that probably cannot be reversed. I wonder what will happen when this enters mainstream awareness.

Comment: I'd argue it would make it extremely more difficult to perform tax calculation if dollar 1 was taxed at 2%, dollar 2 at 2.00012%, dollar 3 at 2.00024%, etc. Is this type of system what you meant ?

Comment: @ApplePie I think it's "Why can't we have a continuous computable function `t(x)` such that `t(AGI)` is anyone's owed income tax?" and do the rounding to the nearest dollar/penny once the function is run.

Comment: @Michael - Where's Clay Shirky: Because 82% of Americans flunked high school algebra?  https://www.forbes.com/sites/stuartanderson/2014/06/30/an-82-percent-failure-rate-on-high-school-algebra-exams/#6e0d0f8f13f1

Comment: I completely agree with the premise of the question, and am underwhelmed by the imagination of most of the answers here.  It would be great if taxation could be simplified to a half-page worksheet that anyone could complete with a four-function calculator.  The nightmare of tax brackets and computation now is a waste of everyone's time and resources.  A simple curve could be implemented that would be easier than what we have now.  If there's any doubt... look at the money wasted on tax prep currently, even by those with simple tax returns.

Comment: A significant part of the general population still firmly beliefs that a raise can result in a loss, because taxes 'jump up' when you come into a new tax bracket; a theoretically impossible behavior. I am quite sure that many people in congress making those laws don't even understand the math correctly. A sad truth in our times; missing elementary math knowledge is considered cool and something to be proud of.

Comment: Could you provide three or four examples of something simpler, remembering that no-one in his right mind is going to trust his tax return to paper and pencil nor even to a calculator?

Comment: I disagree with closing this question as duplicate.  The other question asks how tax brackets work.  This question is asking why we do not use a continuously changing tax rate instead of a marginal tax rate.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Before we discuss why the system is the way it is, it needs to be pointed out that the [effective tax rate is indeed continuous](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/101579/10997) (although it is not mathematically smooth).  The tax you pay does not jump when you cross a bracket threshold.

The main advantage of the marginal system over a continuously changing tax rate is that it is easier to understand.

For example, let's say that my annual income puts me right in the middle of the 22% tax bracket.  I know that if I contribute an extra $1000 to my HSA, I will save exactly $220 on my taxes.  Conversely, if I take a part time job and earn an extra $1000, it will cost me $220 in taxes.  If the rate was continuously changing, it would be much less clear what the tax implications would be for these actions.  Any extra money I earn would not only affect the rate I pay on those dollars, but all the other dollars I had already earned that year.

---

To address some of the "pros" of the proposed system that have been added to your question:

> The commonly held perspective of "There's no point in taking that job for $N/annum because I'd be taxed through the roof." at some salary thresholds would be partially diminished.

This would be true of any progressive tax system, whether it is marginal or a continuously variable rate.  Remember, again, that marginal brackets do not result in a sudden jump in tax paid.

> There's no two ways about it - it [the proposed continuous-spectrum tax rate] would give finer-grained control over income taxation at the expense of ease-of-understanding. It could offer a fairer tax system, in spite of public impression of complexity.

"Fairness" is a loaded term.  There are people who believe that the only fair tax system would be a flat rate for everybody.  There are others who believe that those who earn more should pay a higher rate than those that earn less (progressive taxing, which is what we have now in the U.S.).  But what the marginal rate brackets do is attempt to appease both of those groups.  Those who earn more do indeed pay a higher effective rate on their income than those who pay less.  And yet, everyone, rich or poor, has the first ~$10k of their annual taxable income taxed at 10%, the next ~$30k taxed at 12%, etc.  In that sense, it is quite fair.

> Tax is digital in many countries - we shouldn't have to be narrow-minded about the possibilities for tax any more. Tax tables are (or at least should be) a thing of the past.

As I explained in [my answer to "What's the point of tax tables?"](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/60422/10997), the fact that most people use a computer to calculate their taxes goes both ways.  If you are using a computer, you don't care whether that program is using a formula to calculate your tax or looking it up in a table.  This isn't really an argument to get rid of tax tables.

Comment: It’s not technically continuous, because no function on money can be continuous. Money is quantised. You cannot pay tax equal to exactly 1/3 of $10,000.

Comment: @MikeScott It’s worse than that: Tax returns are done in whole dollars (rounding off the cents), and then the tax you pay is [determined by tax tables](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/60390/10997), where [there are many little tax brackets of income](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi#idm139798481111472) with rounded tax amounts.

Comment: But my point is that the tax table is based on [marginal tax rates](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/taxes/federal-income-tax-brackets/) that produce a continuous function for tax paid and effective tax rate before any rounding due to quantized currency, dollar rounding, or the tax tables.

Comment: Algebraic continuity is like Ɐ x, ε > 0 ∃ δ > 0 : |y - x| < δ → |f(y) - f(x)| < ε . To make sense for taxes we need to modify the definition of "continuity" to accept a certain level of granularity like Ɐ x, ε > $25 ∃ δ > $1.

Comment: Being able to explain/understand the system is an important consideration. So many people can't even understand tax brackets (and think earning more could make you take less money after tax), let alone some continuously increasing function.

Comment: Really, continuity depends on the topology of the domain and range of the function we're considering. Why bother worrying about the technicality of dollars being discrete? Under any useful definition of continuity of functions of dollars, the effective tax rate is continuous.

Comment: This is probably the most compelling reason. To try to get a continuous function from income to tax with the desired characteristics, you either have to go to high order polynomials or some kind of exponential function, both of which can be confusing to a non mathematical educated person, regardless of the actual level of education. Tax brackets are easier to graps, for how complicated they can be.

Comment: The tax is discontinuous, not because of brackets, but because some deductions and adjustments phase out instantly instead of smoothly.

Comment: @bracco23 I don't think an exponential function is too complex for most of the world's earning population - if they have access to state-provided tools which can reliably calculate tax for a given income (likely online or by some other means for others in the population). Enough mathematical tomfoolery occurs behind the scenes with people's money regardless. Base rates play around with savings, salary sacrifices, pensions - the confusion already adds up anyway. Being 2020, I don't think "the maths is harder" should be a reason not to innovate (if indeed it is innovation).

Comment: @BenjaminCrawfordCtrl-Alt-Tut when in my uni I tried to redesign the taxing system that was the main reason for which switching to a continuous smooth function was declined, opting again for a brackets system (in my case, based on family income of the student). I do agree with you that a good optimisation problem could be set up to give a more optimal income to tax function, which result might be a nice smooth function, but that is something for the future I guess.

Answer (score 23):

Historically, taxes had to be calculated (or tax tables compiled) by hand. Taxes in a system of discrete rates and brackets are probably easier to compute by hand.

Nowadays, we could easily compute other mathematical functions using pocket calculators or computers. But to do that we'd have to change the tax code substantially.

First, the legal language to describe brackets is well established, and has been tested in court and refined over decades to avoid challenges by unwilling taxpayers. Changing the language dramatically would risk ambiguous language slipping in to the code, leading to legal challenges and lost revenue under the new code.

Second, other parts of the tax code depend on the bracket structure we have now. So any change to an entirely new system of computing taxes would require scrubbing the entire rest of the tax code (6550 pages of legalese for the US, according to [this](https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/2017/oct/17/roy-blunt/tax-code-so-long-nobodys-really-sure-its-length/)) to make other aspects of the code sensible under the new system. Even laws outside the tax code (for example, who is eligible for welfare programs or higher education grants) might depend on the brackets in the tax code.

Given the sensitivity of the tax code to politics (meaning, many voters have opinions on how they'd like the tax code adjusted to favor them, so all the legislators have an opinion on it), even small changes in the code are difficult to make. It's not surprising nobody wants to make such a fundamental change to the way taxes are calculated.

Answer (score 12):

I suspect it's because a lot of people (including many politicians & bureaucrats) are math-challenged, and find brackets easier to understand than a continuous function.  And at least in the US, most people just look up the amount in the tax tables, anyway :-)

Comment: And even allowing that the quantitative specifics are out of reach, what about simply qualitatively describing such a tax? How many members of Congress, if asked to sketch a “sigmoid-shaped distribution”, would be able to do so? I expect not many. Brackets are easier to explain in legislative language.

Comment: Totally agree. That's the problem of allowing math-oblivious people to write laws involving numbers. They should just write generic laws instead, and having technically competent people refine them.

Comment: @o0'.: I disagree.  As other answers note, brackets & tax tables is much simpler than having to compute a complex function.  It's essentially the same reason that I sometimes use lookup tables rather than expensive computations in performance-critical software.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 "Easier to explain" and easier to [change independently](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/125766/33572).

Comment: I don't think "because people are bad at maths" is a good enough excuse to dismiss the question. I also disagree that using brackets and tax tables is any "simpler" than plugging a figure into an equation at the end of the year. Most employees' income tax (+ NI in UK) is handled at the employer end. We have highly integrated digital payroll and tax systems now which would make short work of even "complex functions." If the individuals are paranoid about it, they can do the maths themselves.

Comment: @jamesqf “quick to compute” and “simple” aren't the same thing. A linear congruential PRNG is also simple to compute, but that doesn't mean it has easy to understand, well-behaved stable behaviour. For tax concerns, the effort of just computing concrete individual values is a non-issue anyway; it's the “what happens to the tax amount if I make such and such decision” where it gets complicated. And for that, a function with good _analytic_ properties might well be advantageous, even if it's slightly more expensive to compute single values.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: And it would be fairly simple (though tedious) to code such a function using existing tables & brackets.

Comment: @Benjamin Crawford Ctrl-Alt-Tut: Dismissing the question?  No, giving a reasonable answer.  Perhaps the tax system is different in the UK, but in the US there are many factors affecting a person's tax that aren't known to the employer - and that's assuming a person is an employee rather someone who works for themselves.  It comes down to the wisdom of replacing a trivially simple system with a much more complicated one.  Even with the simple system, apparently under half of Americans can do their own taxes.

Comment: @jamesqf no, it would be _mathematically impossible_ to code an analytic function that matches the tables/brackets, precisely because those are not continuously differentiable. (You could of course fit an e.g. high-order polynomial as an approximation, but it wouldn't be a good approximation unless you go to such high order that it becomes numerically really problematic.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Not at all. I am using "function" in the C programming sense (as you might have guessed from the word "code" :-)), so all you need to do is tediously type the tax table (or find an on-line version) and do a lookup.

Comment: @jamesqf then you're missing out on all that nice analysis stuff that my point was about. A function in C cannot be differentiated properly (especially if it's a table lookup, where finite-differences is unstable WRT step size), and integrating it is inefficient too. Again: _evaluating_ a given tax rate, that's not an issue anyway with computers (even if the tax were an arcane transcendental function). The higher-level stuff is where performance may become critical, and that's where _mathematically simple_ functions trump “simple (though tedious) to code” ones.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Certainly you can do analysis.  Write the function and surrounding code, run repeatedly varying the inputs in small increments, and plot the results.

Comment: @jamesqf are you even actually _reading_ my comments? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference ...Either way, I think this discussion isn't going anywhere.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Yes, I am reading your comments.  That's why I keep trying to explain why they appear to be... well, to be polite, let's just say disconnected from practical reality :-)  IOW you can do any sort of analysis that you need for practical purposes with a non-continuous function.

Answer (score 11):

Having tax brackets allows you to vary the tax rate for one portion of incomes independently of the other incomes. Say you want to introduce a tax-free part, or increase taxes for the ultra-rich. A continuous and smooth function would either have fewer free parameters, in which case you would change also the other tax rates. Or you have at least one parameter for each income region but then you would have to do a matching between the regions, so that the function is still continuous and smooth, and you would have brackets again.

Answer (score 9):

Because in practice, it's actually quite simple.  It works like this (hypothetical example):

> If your taxable income is between $125,001 and $170,000:
>    Your tax is $16,208 plus 
>    25% of the amount over $125,000.

What's happening is that the tax at exactly $125,000 is known to be $16,208.  So for those inside the 25% bracket running from $125,000 to $170,000, they are simply saying to add 25% of the amount in that bracket,

Comment: I understand how the bracket system works and I'm not suggesting it isn't simple - I'm suggesting it doesn't make sense. How is this any simpler from substituting annual gross income into a formula at the end of the year, a task which would likely be automated by your employer's computer system anyway?

Answer (score 5):

If the tax rate is computed in some way, i.e. it is expressed as some [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) of income, the resulting system is neither intuitive nor simple. In reality, a switch to a system like that is unlikely to be understood as a simplification or perceived as fair.

Another solution is to create a table of effective tax rates, depending on income. That's how income tax is (or was) computed in Geneva, Switzerland. Two drawbacks: that table becomes very long and, unlike brackets, you can still have threshold effects (lower after-tax income following an increase in before-tax income). As a limiting case, you could have an entry in the table for each integer dollar/pound amount but the resulting table would be too unwieldy to handle and would probably have to be used electronically. This too would seem to make the system more complex, not simpler.

At the end of the day, even if many people do struggle to fully understand it, a simple bracket system seems like a decent compromise while providing some element of [progressive taxation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_tax) that many people find desirable and associate with fairness. The only approach that is unambiguously simpler is a [flat tax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_tax), which has its proponents.

Comment: Flat tax is "constant slope with a zero intercept".  There's also "constant slope with a non-zero intercept" which is just about as easy to comprehend and is somewhat progressive and I will abbreviate as "non-zero intercept" or NZI.  Another way to look at it is that flat tax reduces today's system to a single tax bracket removing all others, and NZI tax removes all but one non-zero bracket in today's system but keeps the zero-tax bracket as well.  If you take this NZI tax and implement it by collecting sales tax instead of income tax, you basically have the so-called "FairTax".

Comment: I disagree with practically all of your first paragraph. How it's perceived now, in the long run, isn't important. I think it *is* intuitive to have a continuously varying tax - the more you earn, the higher proportion of tax you pay (to a limit). No part of that statement suggests abrupt jumps in tax rate.

Comment: @BenVoigt Effectively that means two brackets. You add the same complexity while losing much of the progressive taxation aspect so I fail to see what the point would be or why it deserves to be discussed separately. I am also unclear on how you can implement a zero bracket through a sales tax.

Comment: @BenjaminCrawfordCtrl-Alt-Tut It doesn't really matter, my point is that the very fact that “the more you earn, the higher proportion of tax you pay” wouldn't be intuitively clear in the setup you propose. Brackets have exactly the same property and are much more intuitive.

Comment: I also think that how it is perceived now is hugely important, possibly more than in a long run that would never come about if you cannot articulate the benefits of the change. However, I don't think the system would become more intuitive in the long run either. That's why it wouldn't be perceived as fair: not because people have a problem with the tax rate increasing with income but because the system would be completely opaque.

Comment: @Relaxed: FairTax works (would work) by charging flat sales tax and then issuing each legal resident a rebate equal to the tax charged on the zero-tax allowance.  It results in a single line with a non-zero intercept (it isn't even piecewise, because the slope is the same everywhere, going negative if expenditure is below the allowance).  Functionally there's no difference between "flat sales tax with a rebate for taxes paid on the allowance" and "flat sales tax and a universal basic income" if the UBI payment and rebate payment are equal.

Comment: @BenVoigt It's clearer thanks, I think I got confused by the word “rebate”, I thought you were proposing some sort of deduction (which is how the zero-tax bracket works in the countries I am most familiar with). If you implement it as a universal basic income, I see how it could work in practice. However, it's not that progressive and the income tax component is really just a flat tax.

Answer (score 1):

In all countries where I have looked at income tax, it is indeed a smooth function. Germany has one of the more complicate once, using a third degree polynomial (which is probably beyond what most politicians can understand except the odd one with a degree in quantum chemistry), but that was never a problem: They just printed a table with taxes over a reasonable range, and you looked it up in the table. Countries with simpler rules are still too complex for most people to understand.

Most countries (but not all) avoid discontinuities. That is where say one dollar more income would cost you $1000 more in taxes. The obvious reason is that people would then have to worry about how much money you make. Boss offers a 4.5% raise, and you have to go back to him and say "please can you make that 4.4%" because otherwise it costs you more money. And of course it's basically unfair. The UK is very good at unfair taxes. You can save a lot of tax here if you have kids and not a high income. One person working making £45,000 a year is "high income". Two people working making £44,000 each for a total of £88,000 is not "high income".

Comment: You might save a lot of taxes with kids, but you will have less money, because kids cost money. This is also not an unintentional effect, but instead it is an tax instrument used in many countries to ease the burden of families.

Comment: It's not a smooth function in the UK, in the mathematical sense of "smooth" that all derivatives exist and are continuous.

Comment: Dirkk The point was £45,000 = “high income”, 2x£44,000 = “low income” according to U.K. tax law.

Answer (score 0):

> it complicates annual tax calculation, as income needs to first be partitioned

Well, the crux of the issue then is, complicates it compared to what?

In practice there are at least two things people want to know about their tax: how much to pay and how changes in gross income convert to changes in net income.

A piecewise-linear function is easy to differentiate without even knowing what calculus is, and a likewise a piece-wise constant function to integrate. I won't attempt to estimate what proportion of the population are comfortable with calculus, but it's not high. With a bit of strain many people can even do calculations involving marginal rates of tax *in their heads*: "if I get a payrise of 100 a month, how much extra is that in my pocket?". We can sometimes even get close to the right answer in the case where we remember to deduct NI. People don't need to know that they're integrating their (locally constant) tax rate when they do this.

Now, there are people who can't do this at all, and just trust their tax software or their accountant. There are people who could cope with much more calculus, and would happily evaluate the definite integrate of your specified function on the range [salary, salary + 100]. But, broadly speaking, a piece-wise linear function has the property that most people, most of the time, kind of understand what *tax payable* and *marginal tax rate* mean. Many know (in imprecise terms, perhaps) how they relate.

What other functions have the property that people can do that? I don't have a mathematical proof, but I strongly suspect the answer is that only locally-constant and locally-linear functions are any good here. So, to comprehend both tax payable and marginal rate, I think most people will find a piecewise-linear function *less* complicated to deal with, not more complicated, than any smooth non-linear function you care to specify. So, if you introduced one, someone would just approximate it with a piece-wise linear function (a "tax table") for ease of use. Use of that tax table would *simplify*, not *complicate* the everyday person's interaction with tax, compared with doing calculus.

Of course, compared with a simple linear function (or "flat tax rate" as it's known in this context), sure, multiple tax brackets are more complex. The reasons against flat income tax rates are political, and basically tax brackets amount to the "simplest" possible income tax system that is progressive (i.e. marginal rate is not everywhere constant and is everywhere non-decreasing).

Two tax brackets would be enough to achieve that (for example you could have a 0% bracket and then one flat rate beyond that). As for why that's not used in the UK: again political, but it amounts to because politicians like to tinker with income tax rates in a bit more detail than that, but not a lot more detail than that.

I honestly don't think any of your three listed pros would appeal to very many politicians:

- The tax *bracket* isn't the reason some people might be disincentivised to seek high salaries: it's the high average tax rate. Making the function smoother doesn't hide that, only flattening the tax rate would. It might remove some irregularities where, say, someone might make a pension payment that not-coincidentally takes their taxable income exactly to a bracket boundary, but I don't think anyone considers those really problematic.
- The practical political use for nightmarish complexity is in the rules for what is taxable, not the conversion from taxable income to tax payable. So, politicians don't especially want finer-grained control of the latter at the expense of understanding. They're way more interested in fiddling around with tax allowances for particular uses of money (annual changes to pensions, ISAs, allowable business expenses, sketchy investment vehicles) than they are in adding more tax brackets (two in my lifetime in the UK IIRC), let alone making it smooth. Actual fairness debates are around how progressive the system should be and/or what types of person should pay what tax, not around the smoothness of the tax function itself.
- While it's true that tax is digital, and many people will use software for convenience, it doesn't follow that we *want* it to be impracticable for taxpayers to understand and even check those calculations (especially not *after* they've dealt with what is currently the tricky part, deciding what is taxable).

Short answer: tidiness is not considered a virtue in politics. Your proposal primarily adds tidiness, and therefore will not recommend itself to politicians.

Comment: All good practical and political points. The precise mathematical nature of any proposed function for marginal tax rate is perhaps over-specified in my question and therefore in the resultant answers - SE pedantries. None of my points were necessarily aiming to win over politicians, this is purely a question of fairness and precision and could be in many ways seen as a bit of a thought experiment.

Comment: Well, I don't think you can realistically define "fairness" without reference to politics, except in the sense used in a dictatorship, "fairness means whatever one person thinks is fair" :-) My basic point on the mathematical definition is just that anything not piecewise linear is going to be intractable to the average person armed with a calculator: whether what you come up with is really smooth or just has 1 or 2 continuous deriatives doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Unless you're a flat tax proponent (or hey, even a 0 tax proponent), fair insofar as: "You earn more, you pay more tax (with bounds at either end - or not!)." I don't remember the last Great Income Tax Referendum we had, but I could imagine the outcome :-)

Comment: Yeah, you could say that the reason we rarely have referenda in the UK is that it's very rare for politicians to be willing to prioritise one issue over all others, to the point where they will implement the result of the referendum "come what may". A referendum on income tax in effect would remove the ability of the government to mess about with income tax on a semi-regular basis, which is precisely the opposite of what they want (and also probably not what most voters want, given that promises to alter taxes are frequently the reason they vote for one party over another).

Answer (score -2):

What continuous function would you suggest and how would you describe it to an ordinary tax payer?

If you want simplicity and equality, I would suggest a living wage and a flat rate income tax. If all income after the living wage is taxed at a flat rate of 10%, then it wouldn't matter if you lived in the Bowery or Beverly Hills, you would pay an equal proportion of taxes. This should apply equally to *ALL* commercially obtained income. No discounts for losses in past years, for political or charitable donations or for pension investments. If the tax authorities think a charity or pension fund is legitimate and deserves tax refunds, then the tax authorities can pay those refunds. In other words, no loop holes for the wealthy to exploit, after all, the poor can't afford the tax lawyers. You do not need to charge the super-rich a higher rate of tax then the working class, as this has been proven to be counter productive, but the current approach of charging the rich and super rich lower taxes then poorer people is both unjust and unfair and is just increasing the "us and them" divide.

This idea works just as well for commercial ventures as it does for individuals. The difference between the purchase of raw materials and the income from sales is the gross commercial income (gross profit). That income is taxed at the same rate as private income. All of a sudden you have no more mega-corps (Google, Apple, Starbucks, Amazon etc.) getting away with paying no taxes. The company can do what it likes with the remaining profit, re-invest it, pay dividends, but any person or entity receiving that income pays income tax on what they receive.

Comment: downvotes without comments are not very helpful.